# PHP says that this json is invalid because "object property name separator ':' expected", can anyone see why?

Tags: php, json

What's wrong with this json:

```
 { "items" : [ {"timestamp":"1372964400","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373666400","value":"2","nid":"593141","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371398400","value":"1","nid":"34872","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374238800","value":"2","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371902400","value":"1","nid":"79534","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373425200","value":"1","nid":"583657","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376251200","value":"4","nid":"701275","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371330000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372183200","value":"1","nid":"81447","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372348800","value":"2","nid":"83560","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373162400","value":"1","nid":"583657","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374174000","value":"2","nid":"607389","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371834000","value":"2","nid":"79534","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372723200","value":"1","nid":"190555","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373385600","value":"2","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375855200","value":"1","nid":"697831","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372312800","value":"1","nid":"81447","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373047200","value":"2","nid":"545517","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373929200","value":"3","nid":"605563","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375462800","value":"1","nid":"647466","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376434800","value":"5","nid":"704771","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371722400","value":"1","nid":"79534","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372240800","value":"1","nid":"82257","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372687200","value":"1","nid":"190555","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373367600","value":"1","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374634800","value":"1","nid":"610377","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375812000","value":"1","nid":"697482","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372129200","value":"1","nid":"81157","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372287600","value":"1","nid":"79568","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372989600","value":"1","nid":"40191","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373788800","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375376400","value":"1","nid":"646893","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376420400","value":"1","nid":"704624","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371423600","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372230000","value":"7","nid":"81447","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372413600","value":"1","nid":"118275","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373306400","value":"5","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374264000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371960000","value":"1","nid":"79568","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372924800","value":"1","nid":"82456","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373558400","value":"3","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375092000","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376280000","value":"1","nid":"701529","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1370044800","value":"1","nid":"68566","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371380400","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372183200","value":"3","nid":"81457","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372352400","value":"1","nid":"83613","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373194800","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375689600","value":"1","nid":"687547","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371902400","value":"2","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372762800","value":"1","nid":"212931","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375977600","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371322800","value":"2","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372179600","value":"1","nid":"81457","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372345200","value":"2","nid":"83560","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373068800","value":"1","nid":"545517","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374163200","value":"1","nid":"607389","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375470000","value":"1","nid":"647526","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376460000","value":"1","nid":"705149","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1370278800","value":"1","nid":"57508","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371765600","value":"2","nid":"79568","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372690800","value":"1","nid":"212147","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373382000","value":"9","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374674400","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375819200","value":"1","nid":"697482","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371132000","value":"1","nid":"76647","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372143600","value":"1","nid":"81209","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372302000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373036400","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373886000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375380000","value":"1","nid":"646893","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376427600","value":"1","nid":"704735","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1370260800","value":"3","nid":"68984","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372240800","value":"1","nid":"82162","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372428000","value":"1","nid":"154915","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373364000","value":"6","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374606000","value":"1","nid":"610377","platform":"-1"}] }
```

when running json_decode on this string php returns null.
i've checked with every online php json_decoder and they decode it succesfully.
i've also tried with `json_decode($json, TRUE);` but the call also returns NULL

i'm on php version PHP 5.5.1-2+debphp.org~precise+2

I've checked what `json_last_error_msg()` has to say and it returned:
**object property name separator ':' expected**

Comment: Your json seems valid > http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: valid for me too. paste your `json_decode` codes

Comment: Why are you using an RC version of PHP when the final release of 5.4.17 is available? (I can't imagine this will make any difference, but it seems odd)

Comment: See also json_last_error()

Comment: Have you checked what PHP thinks is the problem using the [`json_last_error()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)?

Comment: @Glavić did you even read the question? He already tested jsonlint.com and several others, and they all say it's valid. But PHP fails to decode it.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: The question was "*What's wrong with this json?*" and the answer is "*nothing is wrong with your JSON*".

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: i did tested it on my localhost (v5.4.9), and it was decoded correctly, like on any other online decoder...

Comment: @Blender then he just needs to update the question to include the real problem he's having. Often it's not immediately obvious what the problem is until you research it further. Stack Overflow would be useless if we all just gave up after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me under 5.4.3

```
<?php

$json = '{ "items" : [ {"timestamp":"1372964400","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373666400","value":"2","nid":"593141","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371398400","value":"1","nid":"34872","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374238800","value":"2","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371902400","value":"1","nid":"79534","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373425200","value":"1","nid":"583657","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376251200","value":"4","nid":"701275","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371330000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372183200","value":"1","nid":"81447","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372348800","value":"2","nid":"83560","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373162400","value":"1","nid":"583657","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374174000","value":"2","nid":"607389","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371834000","value":"2","nid":"79534","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372723200","value":"1","nid":"190555","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373385600","value":"2","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375855200","value":"1","nid":"697831","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372312800","value":"1","nid":"81447","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373047200","value":"2","nid":"545517","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373929200","value":"3","nid":"605563","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375462800","value":"1","nid":"647466","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376434800","value":"5","nid":"704771","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371722400","value":"1","nid":"79534","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372240800","value":"1","nid":"82257","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372687200","value":"1","nid":"190555","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373367600","value":"1","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374634800","value":"1","nid":"610377","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375812000","value":"1","nid":"697482","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372129200","value":"1","nid":"81157","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372287600","value":"1","nid":"79568","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372989600","value":"1","nid":"40191","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373788800","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375376400","value":"1","nid":"646893","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376420400","value":"1","nid":"704624","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371423600","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372230000","value":"7","nid":"81447","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372413600","value":"1","nid":"118275","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373306400","value":"5","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374264000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371960000","value":"1","nid":"79568","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372924800","value":"1","nid":"82456","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373558400","value":"3","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375092000","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376280000","value":"1","nid":"701529","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1370044800","value":"1","nid":"68566","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371380400","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372183200","value":"3","nid":"81457","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372352400","value":"1","nid":"83613","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373194800","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375689600","value":"1","nid":"687547","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371902400","value":"2","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372762800","value":"1","nid":"212931","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375977600","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371322800","value":"2","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372179600","value":"1","nid":"81457","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372345200","value":"2","nid":"83560","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373068800","value":"1","nid":"545517","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374163200","value":"1","nid":"607389","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375470000","value":"1","nid":"647526","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376460000","value":"1","nid":"705149","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1370278800","value":"1","nid":"57508","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371765600","value":"2","nid":"79568","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372690800","value":"1","nid":"212147","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373382000","value":"9","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374674400","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375819200","value":"1","nid":"697482","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1371132000","value":"1","nid":"76647","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372143600","value":"1","nid":"81209","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372302000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373036400","value":"1","nid":"545500","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373886000","value":"1","nid":"59251","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1375380000","value":"1","nid":"646893","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1376427600","value":"1","nid":"704735","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1370260800","value":"3","nid":"68984","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372240800","value":"1","nid":"82162","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1372428000","value":"1","nid":"154915","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1373364000","value":"6","nid":"590502","platform":"-1"},{"timestamp":"1374606000","value":"1","nid":"610377","platform":"-1"}] }';

$json_object = json_decode($json);

var_dump($json_object);
```

Maybe it's your `json_decode` that's causing the issue.

You can pass an extra argument to `json_decode` that changes the returned value from an object (by default) to an array.

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

See [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a bug in your installation of PHP (you're using a release candidate, so that could be the issue) or there are some kind of illegal characters in the JSON file, which might not be posted here because stack overflow probably deletes weird characters.

Try a different version of PHP, or try going over the JSON code with a Hex Editor (I like HedFiend personally, but it only works on a mac).

Also try running json_decode() on partial snippets of the string instead of the entire thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to this URL and have a nice look @ your JSON :)

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?